# Keycloak: Authorization between services and the public frontend

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, keycloak, service-accounts

I have an application which consists of a frontend and several backend services. The authentication is done via Keycloak.
The workflow looks like this:
The user logs into the frontend and gets a token from Keycloak. This token is sent to the backend with every request.

The following image explains the current architecture:

[image]

In Keycloak I have the following clients:

**1. Frontend**

- Access Type: public
- Client Protocol: openid-connect

**2. Core Service**

- Access Type: bearer-only
- Client Protocol: openid-connect

**3. User Service**

- Access Type: bearer-only
- Client Protocol: openid-connect

How can I validate calls between services now?

I would imagine something like a service account and these have the possibility to call each other independently from the bearer-token from the frontend. The problem is that both services can be called from the frontend as well as between each other.

**Edit:**

My API is written with NestJS.

The API of the user-service:
[image]

And this is how I call the user-service in my core-service:
[image]

and this is my keycloak configuration for the the user-service:
[image]

At the moment I don't add anything to the request and I don't have any extra configuration on the interface. So I added the `@Resource('user-service')`-Annotation to the Controller and the `@Scope()`-Annotation to the Endpoint.

After that I don't get an error immediately and the endpoint is called.I can log that the logic is executed. But as response I still get a 401 Unauthorized Error.

Do I need to specify a scope or what do I need to add in the `@Resource`-Annotation?

**Edit 2:**

I'll try to show you my current situation with many screenshots.

## Initial situation

[image]

Here is your drawing again. For me, points 1-5 work and point 8 works even if I do not call another service.

## My Configuration

That this works, I have the following configuration:

### Just Frontend and Core Service

Frontend:
[image]

Core-Service:
[image]

For the core service (gutachten-backend), I do not need to make any further configurations for this. I also have 2 different roles and I can specify them within the API.

Using Postman I send a request to the API and get the token from http://KEYCLOAK-SERVER_URL/auth/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token.

[image]

These are my 2 testing methods. I call the first one and it works. The following is logged. Means the token is validated received and I get Access:
[image]

### Calling the user service

Now I call the second method. This method calls the user-service.

This is my request in the core-service:
[image]
I do not add anything else to my request. Like a bearer token in the header.

The endpoint in the user service is just a test method which logs a message.

This is my configuration for the user service:
[image]

I have now tried something with resources, policies and permissions.

#### Resource

[image]

#### Policies

Role-Policy
[image]

Client-Policy:
[image]

#### Permission

[image]

And analogously the client permission

## Questions and thoughts

- All steps from the first drawing seem to work except 6 and 7
- Do I need to add more information to my request from core service to user service?
- How to deal with root url and resource urls?
- In the code in the API, do I need to additionally configure the endpoints and specify the specific resources and policies? (NestJS offers the possibility to provide controllers with a `@Resource('<name>')` and endpoints with `@Scopes([<list>]))`
  Additionally, through a tutorial on setting up keyacloak in NestJS, I turned on the following config:

> This adds a global level resource guard, which is permissive.
> Only controllers annotated with @Resource and
> methods with @Scopes are handled by this guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who have the same problem in the future. The answer from @BenchVue helped a lot to understand the concept in general.

What was missing is that a token must also be added for each request between services. Namely the token of the client.

So before the request is sent, the following query takes place. This is the method to get the token for a client:

```
getAccessToken(): Observable<string> {
    const header = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    };
    return this.httpService.post(
      '{{keycloakurl}}/auth/realms/{{realm}}/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={{clientId}}&client_secret={{clientSecret}}`,
      header).pipe(
        map((response) => {
          return response.data.access_token as string;
        }
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak's **Token Verification API** can do it.

This is one of Architecture for Authorization of resource access permission.

[image]

Between Core Service and User Service, Core Service needs to verify the access-token to Keycloak.
It means this token can access the User service API Yes(Allow) or No(Deny)

This is [API format](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_create_resource)

```
curl -X POST \
  http://${host}:${port}/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" \
  --data "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket" \
  --data "audience={resource_server_client_id}" \
  --data "permission=Resource A#Scope A" \
  --data "permission=Resource B#Scope B"
```

Demo Keycloak Token URL: **localhost:8180**

Authorization Enabled Realm: **test**

Authorization Enabled Client: **core-service**

Client Resource: **resource:user-service**

**User1** : can access it (**ALLOW**) password: 1234

**User2** : can access it (**ALLOW**) password:1234

#### Steps

Get User Access Token(instead of login) ->

1. Preparations
   ready to assign access-token(named user-token) variable in Postman

[image]

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("user-token", jsonData.access_token);
```

Get Token URL from Keycloak UI, click the *Endpoints*
[image]

[image]

2. Get User1's access token
   with Bearer Token option with {{user-token}} in Authorization Tab
   [image]

[image]

3. Verify with user1 token from Core Service to Keycloak
   return 200 OK from Keycloak (ALLOW) - it is Circle 4 and 5 in my Architecture.
   So Core Service forward API call to User Service for accessing service
   ***Note*** - ***needs to finish Keycloak Permission setting***

[image]

4. Verify with user2 token from Core Service to Keycloak
   return 200 OK from Keycloak (Allow) too.
   So Core Service return an error to Front-end, like this user can't access a resource of User Service.

More detail information is in [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_permission_create_resource)

#### Keycloak Permission setting

1. Create Client
2. Create Client Resource
3. Add Client Role
4. Add Client Policy
5. Add Permission
6. All user mapping into Client role

This is Configuration in Keycloak
Create Client
[image]

Create Client Resource

[image]

Add Client Role
[image]

[image]

Add Client Policy - role based
[image]
[image]

Add Permission
[image]

All user mapping into Client role - any user if you want to add to access the resource.
[image]

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I have managed the configuration so far. I still have a question about the policy. you have created a policy that applies to certain users. I want every call from the service to be allowed, regardless of the user calling the api. Is it correct that I then create a "client policy" and specify the "user-service" in the core service?

Comment: But I still get an error with 401 unauthorized. I edited my question with more details. would be great if you knew an answer to this question

Comment: @ManuelWolf, Added more detail to avoid 401 Error. Hope to help it. if still 401 error, let me know which step's get 401 error. This change support all users.  I have no experience nestJs + Keycloak. Which middle ware use for NestJS to access Keycloak?
I will try but It will takes time, I will update again If I success it.

Comment: I have now added a hopefully understandable, detailed description under Edit 2. Für NestJS I use "nest-keycloak-connect" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nest-keycloak-connect)

Comment: Thanks, I started to learn "nest-keycloak-connect" give me a couple of days more.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately I still have the problem. Did you have time to look at the package and did you understand it. I would be very happy about an answer/help.

Comment: Hi @ManuelWolf, I am sorry, I try it but not success to figure out NextJS. you needs to figure out yourself.